# Problema em função de adicionar no fim de uma Lista Encadeada Simples

Tags: java, recursão, lista-encadeada

Tenho uma lista encadeada simples e preciso fazer uma função recursiva que adiciona no fim da lista um elemento, já tenho a função sem recursividade, mas a com recursividade está dando erro. Segue o código e o erro:

**Função sem recursividade:**

```
void addFim(int chave) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            addInicio(chave);
            return;
        }

        Node novo = new Node(chave);
        ultimo.prox = novo;
        ultimo = novo;
        N++;
    }
```

**Função com recursividade:**

```
void addFimRecursivo(int chave) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            addInicio(chave);
            N++;
            return;
        }

        addFimRecursivo(null, primeiro, chave);
    }

    private void addFimRecursivo(Node anterior, Node atual, int chave) {
        if(atual.prox == null) {
            Node novo = new Node(chave);
            ultimo.prox = novo;
            ultimo = novo;
            N++;
        }

        addFimRecursivo(atual, atual.prox, chave);

    }
```

**Erro:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

**Lista:**

```
class Lista {

    private Node primeiro;
    private Node ultimo;
    private int N;

    /* construtor vazio */
    Lista() {
    }

    /* construtor */
    Lista(Node primeiro) {

        Node x;

        for (x = primeiro; x != null; x = x.prox) {
            addInicio(x.chave);
        }

    }

    void addInicio(int chave) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            primeiro = new Node(chave);
            ultimo = primeiro;
            N++;
            return;
        }

        Node novo = new Node(chave);
        novo.prox = primeiro;
        primeiro = novo;
        N++;
    }

    void addFim(int chave) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            addInicio(chave);
            return;
        }

        Node novo = new Node(chave);
        ultimo.prox = novo;
        ultimo = novo;
        N++;
    }

    void addFimRecursivo(int chave) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            addInicio(chave);
            N++;
            return;
        }

        addFimRecursivo(null, primeiro, chave);
    }

    private void addFimRecursivo(Node anterior, Node atual, int chave) {
        if(atual.prox == null) {
            Node novo = new Node(chave);
            ultimo.prox = novo;
            ultimo = novo;
            N++;
        }

        addFimRecursivo(atual, atual.prox, chave);

    }

    void addEmOrdem(int chave) {

        if (isEmpty()) {
            addInicio(chave);
            return;
        }

        addEmOrdem(null, primeiro, chave);
    }

    void addEmOrdem(Node anterior, Node atual, int chave) {

        Node novo = new Node(chave);

        if (size() == 1) {
            if (chave < primeiro.chave) {
                addInicio(chave);
                return;
            } else {
                primeiro.prox = novo;
            }
            N++;
            return;
        }

        if (chave < atual.chave) {
            anterior.prox = novo;
            novo.prox = atual;
            return;
        }

        addEmOrdem(atual, atual.prox, chave);
    }

    void remove(int chave) {

        if (chave == primeiro.chave) {
            removeInicio();
            return;
        }

        remove(null, primeiro, chave);
    }

    private void remove(Node anterior, Node atual, int chave) {
        if (atual.chave == chave) {

            if (chave == ultimo.chave) {
                anterior.prox = null;
                ultimo = anterior;
                return;
            }

            Node sucessor = atual.prox;
            anterior.prox = sucessor;
            return;
        }

        remove(atual, atual.prox, chave);
    }

    void removeInicio() {
        primeiro = primeiro.prox;
    }

    void removeFim() {
        removeFim(null, primeiro);
    }

    private void removeFim(Node anterior, Node atual) {
        if (atual.prox == null) {
            anterior.prox = null;
            ultimo = anterior;
            return;
        }

        removeFim(atual, atual.prox);
    }

    void removeNInicio(int chave) {
        if (size() == 1) {
            removeInicio();
            return;
        }

        removeNInicio(null, primeiro, chave);
    }

    private void removeNInicio(Node anterior, Node atual, int chave) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= chave; i++) {
            atual = atual.prox;
            removeNInicio(atual, atual.prox, chave);
        }   
    }

    void imprime() {
        imprime(primeiro);
    }

    void imprime_invertido() {
        imprime_invertido(primeiro);
    }

    void imprime_invertido(Node x) {

    }

    private void imprime(Node x) {
        if (x == null) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println(x.chave);
        imprime(x.prox);
    }

    Node metade() {
        int m = N / 2;
        return metade(primeiro, m);
    }

    Node metade(Node x, int m) {
        if (m == 0) {
            return x;
        }

        return metade(x.prox, m - 1);
    }

    boolean isEmpty() {
        return primeiro == null;
    }

    int size() {
        return N;
    }

}
```

**Testa Lista:**

```
class TestaLista {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Lista lista = new Lista();

        lista.addEmOrdem(1);
        lista.addEmOrdem(5);
        lista.addEmOrdem(2);
        lista.addEmOrdem(3);
        lista.addEmOrdem(4);

        lista.imprime(); 
    }

}
```

**Node :**

```
class Node {

    int chave;
    Node prox;
    Node ant;

    Node(int chave) {
        this.chave = chave;
    }

}
```

Creio que o erro seja na recursão, mas não estou conseguindo arrumar!

Comment: O código inteiro não, mas fornecer um **[mcve]** é sim, necessário.

Comment: @Articuno coloquei um exemplo de função recursiva "removeFim()" que está funcionando, creio que seja o necessário, se não for, me avise

Comment: Não é, veja o link que mandei. Nele ensina como criar um código relevante, onde seja possivel testar.

Comment: Se eu copiar o seu código para o meu Eclipse, Netbeans ou outra coisa parecida, ele compila? Não. É simples e trivial mexer em alguma coisa (como por exemplo, `import`s) para que ele compile? Não. Então o seu exemplo não é mínimo, completo e verificável porque ele falha na parte do "completo" e do "verificável". Faltam partes importantes do código para caracterizar o problema. Dessa forma, fica extremamente difícil dar alguma resposta satisfatória à pergunta.

Comment: @VictorStafusa pronto, preferi colocar o código inteiro para ficar mais fácil de entender as funções e também para conseguir compilar!!

Comment: Ainda não consigo compilar porque não tenho a classe `Node`.

Comment: @VictorStafusa vdd, vou adicionar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você esqueceu um `return` no final do `if` do `addFimRecursivo`:

```
private void addFimRecursivo(Node anterior, Node atual, int chave) {
    if(atual.prox == null) {
        Node novo = new Node(chave);
        ultimo.prox = novo;
        ultimo = novo;
        N++;
        return; // Faltou isso daqui.
    }

    addFimRecursivo(atual, atual.prox, chave);

}
```

No entanto, faço mais algumas sugestões:

- Observe que o parâmetro `anterior` no método `addFimRecursivo` nunca é usado e portanto você pode eliminá-lo facilmente.
- Mover alguns métodos para dentro da classe `Node` deixaria o código mais simples.
- Não se esqueça de usar os modificadores `public` e `private`.
- Usar `N` como tamanho da lista não é um bom nome de variável e vai contra as convenções do código. Prefira `tamanho`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, principalmente pela paciência, ainda estou aprendendo a usar a plataforma.